# Parse.com whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery doesn't work

Tags: java, parse-platform

I have a relatively simple app that shows quotes to a user. when the user have seen the quote, it is added as a "seenQuote" relationship to the user table so he doesn't see it again. However when I want to retrieve new quotes which the user  haven't seen it still returns the seenQuotes.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
final ParseQuery<Quote> newQuotes = new ParseQuery<Quote>(Quote.class);
final ParseRelation<ParseObject> seenQuotes = user.getRelation("seenQuotes");

newQuotes.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", seenQuotes.getQuery());

newQuotes.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Quote>() {
  @Override public void done(List<Quote> quotes, ParseException e) {
    // Still contains quotes that have been seen 
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you found your answer? I have the same kind of problem, only when the "key" and "keyInQuery" parameters of whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery are named the same